# Linked keyboard keys are behaving differently than the form buttons they're linked to

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, user-interface, keyboard

I'm programming a calculator application, and I want to link buttons with their associated keyboard keys. When I click the keyboard keys, it populates the textbox, but isn't saving the values the way it does when I click the form buttons, and operator keys are displaying in the textbox when they're not supposed to.

Here is my code:

```
private void Form1_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            switch (e.KeyCode)
            {
                case Keys.D0:
                    btn0.PerformClick();
                    break;

                case Keys.D1:
                    btn1.PerformClick();
                    break;

                case Keys.D2:
                    btn2.PerformClick();
                    break;

                case Keys.D3:
                    btn3.PerformClick();
                    break;

                case Keys.D4:
                    btn4.PerformClick();
                    break;

                case Keys.D5:
                    btn5.PerformClick();
                    break;

                case Keys.D6:
                    btn6.PerformClick();
                    break;

                case Keys.D7:
                    btn7.PerformClick();
                    break;

                case Keys.D8:
                    btn8.PerformClick();
                    break;

                case Keys.D9:
                    btn9.PerformClick();
                    break;

                case Keys.Add:
                    btnAdd.PerformClick();
                    break;

                case Keys.Subtract:
                    btnSubtract.PerformClick();
                    break;

                case Keys.Multiply:
                    btnMultiply.PerformClick();
                    break;

                case Keys.Divide:
                    btnDivide.PerformClick();
                    break;

                case Keys.Decimal:
                    btnDecimalPoint.PerformClick();
                    break;

                case Keys.Back:
                    btnBack.PerformClick();
                    break;

                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
        private void NumberButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (txtBoxString == "0")  //Gets rid of unwanted leading zeroes
            {
                txtDisplayCalculations.Text = "";
                txtBoxString = "";
            }

            string numberButtonClicked; //String will hold most recent digit

            string senderString = sender.ToString(); //The the string associated with sender
            string[] senderNumber = senderString.Split(); //Split the string 
            numberButtonClicked = senderNumber.Last(); //Get the button's text from the string

            txtBoxString += numberButtonClicked; //Add the most recent digit to the number string
            txtDisplayCalculations.Text = txtBoxString; //Display string in textbox


        }
```

Comment: I'm guessing that you should have set text box read only.

Comment: Please provide more detail about what "operator keys are displaying in the textbox when they're not supposed to."

Answer (score 0):

As **proximab** said, you could set textbox's `ReadOnly` property to `true`.

```
textBox.ReadOnly = true;
```

In this way, the textbox can only get the value by clicking the button.

> but isn't saving the values the way it does when I click the form buttons

Does it mean that the input value not recorded? Try to add a break point in `Form1_KeyUp` to check if the event triggered.

If not, set the form's `KeyPreview` property to `true`.

```
this.KeyPreview = true;
```

> operator keys are displaying in the textbox when they're not supposed to

Since there is no code for operator related buttons, we cannot reproduce the problem you described. Please provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), such as `1+1`.